# Field Level Security in Mulesoft using the user's sessionId in Salesforce connector

Tags: query, field-level-security, mulesoft

I am trying to perform a query in Anypoint Studio on the Account standard object. In the Salesforce standard connector 'Query' configuration I implemented the use of the user's sessionId. So if this is passed in the request header, the query is performed as the logged in user. However this causes the query to fail if the user does not have read permission on all the fields included in the query.

Is there a way to avoid the query from failing, e.g. by returning only the fields on which the user has read permission and not the others?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the out of box API. You can certainly build an API in apex that can use the [Stripinaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) apex class to achieve this.